# How to setup distributed JMeter load testing using one local machine as a client and aws VM instances as servers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter, load-testing

I want to set up load testing environment using JMeter and my local machine as a client and some AWS Ubuntu instances as servers. I followed almost every article and answers like this [Setting up JMeter for Distributed testing in AWS with connectivity issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618915/setting-up-jmeter-for-distributed-testing-in-aws-with-connectivity-issues) and youtube tutorial but I get different exceptions every time. Can someone describe clearly step by step how to do that?

also, I can't find a clear answer to these questions:

- Which changes needed only in the jmeter.properties on the server-side or
  only on the client-side and which changes needed on both sides?
- Do I need to change firewall config to allow some ports?
- Will the client machine run part of the tests or not?

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, check whether you're [behind NAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250097/how-can-i-know-if-my-computer-is-behind-nat), if it is the case - you won't be able to have the master locally, you will have to put it into AWS as well
2. The ports which need to be allowed in OS firewall and [AWS Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html) are:

   - `1099` or whatever is your `server_port`
   - the port you define as `server.rmi.localport`
   - the port(s) you define as  `client.rmi.localport`

More information: [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

You might also find wrapper scripts like [JMeter ec2 Script](https://github.com/oliverlloyd/jmeter-ec2) useful